# Trying to get an app to show network error alert codes?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios, ios4

Ok so I am trying to get this app to show network error alert codes. I have added the SystemConfiguration.framework framework and Apple's "Reachability" sample code.

Here is the viewcontroller.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class Reachability;

@interface Test_Internet_ConnectionViewController : UIViewController {

   Reachability* internetReachable;
   Reachability* hostReachable;
}

- (void) checkNetworkStatus:(NSNotification *)notice;

@end
```

And here is the viewcontroller.m file:

```
#import "Test_Internet_ConnectionViewController.h"
#import "Reachability.h";

@implementation Test_Internet_ConnectionViewController



/*
// The designated initializer. Override to perform setup that is required before the view is loaded.
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
}
    return self;
    }
*/

/*
// Implement loadView to create a view hierarchy programmatically, without using a nib.
- (void)loadView {
}
*/


// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

        // check for internet connection
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(checkNetworkStatus:) name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];

        internetReachable = [[Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection] retain];
        [internetReachable startNotifier];

        // check if a pathway to a random host exists
        hostReachable = [[Reachability reachabilityWithHostName: @"www.apple.com"] retain];
        [hostReachable startNotifier];

        // now patiently wait for the notification
    }

/*
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
*/

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void) checkNetworkStatus:(NSNotification *)notice
{
    // called after network status changes

    NetworkStatus internetStatus = [internetReachable currentReachabilityStatus];
    switch (internetStatus)

    {
        case NotReachable:
        {
            NSLog(@"The internet is down.");
            self.internetActive = NO;

            break;

        }
        case ReachableViaWiFi:
        {
            NSLog(@"The internet is working via WIFI.");
            self.internetActive = YES;

            break;

        }
        case ReachableViaWWAN:
        {
            NSLog(@"The internet is working via WWAN.");
            self.internetActive = YES;

            break;

        }
    }

    NetworkStatus hostStatus = [hostReachable currentReachabilityStatus];
    switch (hostStatus)

    {
        case NotReachable:
        {
            NSLog(@"A gateway to the host server is down.");
            self.hostActive = NO;

            break;

        }
        case ReachableViaWiFi:
        {
            NSLog(@"A gateway to the host server is working via WIFI.");
            self.hostActive = YES;

            break;

        }
        case ReachableViaWWAN:
        {
            NSLog(@"A gateway to the host server is working via WWAN.");
            self.hostActive = YES;

            break;

        }
    }
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];




        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];

    }

@end
```

I get 6 errors:

Request for member 'internetActive' in something not a structure or union (3 times)
Request for member 'hostActive' in something not a structure or union (3 times)

Comment: You should accept more answers. 9% is a low and an odd accept ratio. IT's not good for getting answres.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I am very new to this website. Well like 1 week or 2 weeks new.

Comment: Instead of me posting another question, does anyone have any idea of why the app runs with no errors or warnings but it doesn't give me an error alert when there is no internet connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you creating 'internetActive' and 'hostActive' as class variables or as properties anywhere? I don't see this anywhere in the code you provided.

Comment: I don't think I am, please can you tell me how to do this?

Comment: Just add @property (nonatomic) BOOL internetActive; and @property (nonatomic) BOOL hostActive; to the header file for the class, and then synthesize them in the implementation file. Then you can get at them from any object in the class.

Comment: Thank so much, it runs now with no errors or warnings, but there is no error message when I turn airport off?

Comment: Does the app have to be trying to access something that requires an internet connection for the error to show? Because the app contains no other code in whatsoever.